# Fastest way to join 2 tables to get the most recent record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

First one is `bom`

| Article |
| --- |
| AB |
| CD |
| EF |
| GH |

```
CREATE TABLE bom
(
    Article VARCHAR(250)
);

INSERT INTO bom (Article)
 VALUES
 ('AB'),
 ('CD'),
 ('EF'),
 ('GH');
```

Second one is `purchases`

| Article | OrderDate | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | '2020-01-10' | 12 |
| AB | '2020-01-05' | 10 |
| AB | '2020-01-03' | 8 |
| EF | '2020-01-01' | 7 |

```
 CREATE TABLE purchases
(
    Article VARCHAR(250),
    OrderDate DATE,
    Price DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO purchases (Article, OrderDate, Price)
 VALUES
 ('AB', '2020-01-10', 12.0),
 ('AB', '2020-01-05', 10.0),
 ('AB', '2020-01-03', 8.0),
 ('EF', '2020-01-01', 7.0);
```

I want to extract the most recent price for each row of `Article` at a given date.
For instance, at `@evalDay = '2020-01-04'`, I want to get

| Article | OrderDate | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | '2020-01-03' | 8 |
| EF | '2020-01-01' | 7 |

I've managed it to work using a *window function (`row_number() over`)*, but the performance is not as good as I need. This is a simplified example, but my `bom` table has a few hundred of rows, whereas the `purchases` has about 1 million rows. On my computer, it takes approx. 50ms to execute. Of course I use indexes and compound indexes.

My solution:

```
set @evalDay = '2020-01-04';
with cte (Article, OrderDate, Price, rn) as (
    select purchases.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by bom.article
            order by purchases.OrderDate desc
        ) as rn
    from bom
        join purchases on bom.Article = purchases.Article
    where purchases.OrderDate <= @evalDay
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

In this case, what's the fastest approach to get the answer?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your complete statement with window function? How long does a normal join take on your site?

Comment: have you tried to filter via `MAX` function? `WHERE purchases.OrderDate = (SELECT MAX(OrderDate) FROM purchases)`

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely? PS. First row per group - trivial task.

Comment: @Sebastian Siemens I've added my solution to the post

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following approaches:

- Move the join to outside

```sql
with cte (Article, OrderDate, Price, rn) as (
select *,
       row_number() over (partition by article order by OrderDate desc) as rn
    from purchases
   where OrderDate <= @evalDay)
select cte.*, bom.*
  from cte
  join bom
    on cte.Article = bom.Article
 where cte.rn = 1;
```

- Remove the join if no additional columns needed from `bom`

```sql
with cte (Article, OrderDate, Price, rn) as (
select *,
       row_number() over (partition by article order by OrderDate desc) as rn
    from purchases
   where OrderDate <= @evalDay)
select *
  from cte
 where rn = 1;
```

If the above still doesn't perform, consider creating a table to store the result (`Article`,`OrderOdate`,`Price`,`evalDate`) partitioned by `evalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one row in purchases which has the same latest date for the same Article, this might not give you what you want but it's a fairly simple query....

```
set @evalDay = '2020-01-04';
Select a.*
From purchases a, 
  (select Article, Max(OrderDate) AS ODate
  from purchases
  where OrderDate <= @evalDay
  group by Article) b
Where a.Article = b.Article
And a.OrderDate = b.ODate;
```